# Get the text inside TD by neighbouring TH inner text

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

i need to get the value of a specific TD which has no ID or Class by the text value of a neighbouring TH using jQuery

**Example:**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Established</th>
            <td>1976</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Location</th>
            <td>Baltimore, Maryland</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to get the year 1976 (using jQuery) by searching for "Established"
**the location of the tr / order isnt always the same.**

Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var year = $("th:contains('Established')").next().text();

console.log(year); // "1976"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Established</th>
            <td>1976</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Location</th>
            <td>Baltimore, Maryland</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

the above code will work given the string `Established` will always be in that format (First-uppercase, no spaces, etc).
**A more robust solution:**

```js
var year = $("th").filter(function(){
  return /^established$/i.test($.trim($(this).text()));
}).nextAll().filter(function() { // If there's more sibling TD...
  // get all that have exactly 4 numbers as text
  return /^\d{4}$/.test($.trim($(this).text()));
}).first().text(); // ...but get the first one's text.

console.log(year); // "1976"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th> EstablishEd   </th> <!-- Contains spaces and possible uppercase errors? -->
            <td>1976</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Location</th>
            <td>Baltimore, Maryland</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Workers</th>
            <td>3100</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/
https://api.jquery.com/next/
https://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Whattttt? so simple? very nice!!

Comment: @SagiveSEO Thx! THere's also more bulletproof ways to do it, but yes, that's the simplest

Comment: first time i have to wait for time to pass in order to approve answer ;) - 10x a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. jQuery's [`.filter(callback)`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) method can be used to filter elements based on their content.

- Select `th` elements
- Filter selected `th` elements to only have "Established" ones
- Select the `td` elements that follow these `th` elements

```js
var years = $("th").filter(function() { //Get th elements that has "Established" as their text
  return $(this).text() === "Established";
}).next("td"); //Get td elements that are next to these th elements;

console.log(years.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Established</th>
      <td>1976</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Location</th>
      <td>Baltimore, Maryland</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```